# Difference between Flask(__name__) and create_app()?

Tags: flask

I am new to web dev (Flask) and I have seen different developers defining the app variable differently.

Some use

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

While others use

```
app = create_app()
```

What is the difference between the 2?

Answer (score 0):

`app = Flask(__name__)` gives access to `flask.current_app` but `create_app()` doesn't. However, using `create_app()` is better if you want different configurations to be loaded more easily.

For example, if I have `app = Flask(__name__)` then using dynamic configuration is a pain since you have to go through `if` and `elif` and `else` and `sys.args`.

For `create_app()` you can change configuration by just adding a `config` argument or something of the sort. For example, in an app that I have made, I used `create_app()` with a debug attribute so I can edit configuration for a debug mode (reraising errors in my handler, etc.).

The choice is entirely up to you, depending on whether you can sacrifice `current_app` outside of request contexts or not.

Hope this helps.